# Command line installers

Tags: macos, macports

Ok I want to install the command line version of git on a Mac OSX machine.

Should I be using "brew" or macports or something else?

I want a good command line software manager and there are many.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install xcode 4 from AppStore.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12

This will install all developer tools, including git.

For other things I recommend MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

Git has installer for MacOSX.

See http://git-scm.com/download

Github has pretty good instruction on how to setup Git on Mac.

http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/

Answer (score 0):

You can grab git for Mac OSX here: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/